# Ejecutar función después de que Filestack termine de ejecutar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando Filestack v3, quiero comparar la cantidad de palabras con la cantidad de páginas de archivos de word (DOC/DOCX). Bajo la premisa: "Cada página tiene 200 palabras" quiero formular, por ejemplo: "Si un documento tiene 2 páginas, en teoría, tiene 400 palabras, si tiene 400 o más de esa cantidad está OK, de lo contrario está WRONG".

Por tanto este es mi código:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="files">UPLOAD</button>
<textarea id="dkd"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="text" id="cnw">
<input type="text" id="cnp">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.filestackapi.com/v3/filestack.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi código JS es:

```
$("#files").click(function(){
  var client = filestack.init('myAPI');

  client.pick({
    accept: ['image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif','application/pdf','application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'],
    fromSources: ['local_file_system','googledrive','gmail','facebook','dropbox','onedrive','webcam'],
    lang: 'es',     
    maxSize: 2097152,
    maxFiles: 100
  }).then(function(Blobs) {

  var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Blobs));

  for(var i=0; i<result.filesUploaded.length; i++){

    if(result.filesUploaded[i].mimetype=="application/msword" || result.filesUploaded[i].mimetype=="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"){

        var dataFile = "https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/output=docinfo:true/"+result.filesUploaded[i].handle;
        var handlee = result.filesUploaded[i].handle;
        var lcconvert = "https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/"+result.filesUploaded[i].handle;

        //OBTENER NÚMERO DE PALABRAS
        $("#dkd").load(lcconvert, function(){               
            $.post("load2.php",{
                url: $("#dkd").val()
            }).success(function(response){

                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='mswcount' value='"+response+"'>";
                var arr = document.getElementsByName('mswcount');
                var tot=0;
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

                }                       

                document.getElementById('cnw').value = tot;

            });
        });

        //OBTENER NÚMERO DE PÁGINAS
        $.post("numpage.php",{
            dF: dataFile
        }).success(function(response){

            var numpages = $.trim(response);// número de páginas
            $("#cnp").val(numpages);

        });//post
    }//if
  }//for

  inspire();

 });//client.pick
});//files


//COMPARACIÓN
function inspire(){

   var pag = $("#cnp").val();//páginas
   var pagpal = pag*200; //número de páginas * 200 = número de palabras
   var pal = $("#cnw").val();//palabras

   console.log("Páginas: "+pag);
   console.log("Palabras: "+pal);

   if(pal>=pagpal){
      console.log("OK");
   } else {
      console.log("WRONG");
   }
}
```

Quiero que la función llamada **inspire** haga la comparación con los valores en los input y mostrar el resultado en la consola (número de páginas, número de palabras y el mensaje final), pero el problema es que la función inspire se ejecuta antes de que Filestack termine.

Quiero que primero Filestack termine de ejecutarse poniendo los valores en los input y luego se ejecute la función inspire.

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Ahora mismo no puedo comprobarlo pero me parece que lo que necesitas es llamar a esa función en el .onSuccess del pickup https://www.filestack.com/docs/javascript-api/pick

Answer (score 0):

eso se debe a que se esta ejecutando la llamada $post (ajax) de manera asincrona , para solucionar esto de fomra rapida te diria que pusiaras la llamad aa tu funcion dentro del success del la llamada AJAX

```
$.post("numpage.php",{
        dF: dataFile
    }).success(function(response){

        var numpages = $.trim(response);// número de páginas
        $("#cnp").val(numpages);
        inspire();
    });//post
```

Sino la otra opción que tienes es empaquetar todo el código que creas que se ha de ejecutar antes y empaquetarlo en una función y hacer un callback para que se ejecute  después de el código